# OCaml, I don't see effect print_int

Tags: list, ocaml

I'm working in OCaml-top.
And we have a list :

```
let lst = [1;2;3;4] ;;
iter (fun x -> pint_int x) lst ;;
```

But Only that I see is `- : unit = ()`

Why doesn't it write a list ?

Comment: I guess you mean `print_int`?

Answer (score 1):

Buffered I/O. Add

```
flush stdout;;
```

at the end of your script.

Comment: The OP wrote "OCaml-top", this sounds more like the interpreter (i.e., OCaml toplevel) than a script. There it should in principle work without flushing.

Comment: I thought he uses this program:  http://www.typerex.org/ocaml-top.html
It's not a normal toplevel and gtk introduces additional quirks. You need flushing in this case.